# Filter LiveData<Map> by another LiveData<String> android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I have a LiveData`<Map<A, List<B >>` that comes from Room Database and I have also a searchQuery that I want to Filter the B objects by. For example,

```
data class Server(
   val serverId: Int
)

data class Group(
   val serverId: Int,
   val groupId: Int,
   val description: String
)

LiveData<Map<Server, List<Group>>

So I have 
Server(100)
Group(100, 1, "AAAA")
Group(100, 2, "AAAB")
Group(100, 3, "AABB")

Server(200)
Group(200, 1, "AAAA")
Group(200, 2, "AAAB")
Group(200, 3, "AABB")
```

Now, I have a `searchableString = "BB"`
So the LiveData I want it to be filtered on the description field and the result must be

```
Server(100)
Group(100, 3, "AABB")

Server(200)
Group(200, 3, "AABB")
```

Is there any way to do this on Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write an extension function to filter your map:

```
fun Map<Server, List<Group>>.filterGroups(descFilter: String) = mapValues { _, groups ->
    groups.filter { descFilter in it.description }
}
```

If you want to eliminate empty servers, you could tack on a `.filter { _, groups -> groups.isNotEmpty() }` to the end of the above function.

Assuming your LiveData is in a view model, I would create a private MutableLiveData for the search term with a public property to change it. Then use `switchMap` to produce the final result based on your input.

```
val sourceMapFromRoom: LiveData<Map<Server, List<Group>> = //...

private val _searchFilter = MutableLiveData<String>("")

val searchFilter: String
    get() = _searchFilter.value
    set(value) { _searchFilter.value = value }

val filteredMap = _searchFilter.switchMap { searchString ->
    sourceMapFromRoom.map { it.filterGroups(searchString) }
}
```

`switchMap` is the LiveData equivalent of `flatMapLatest` in Rx or Kotlin Flows.

Comment: Thats correct. Thnx